# can I use bulk update API on the same document in Elasticsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I have a lambda take streaming update events from Dyanmodb table and save these events to Elasticsearch index. In order to improve the performance, I am using bulk update API. But the events from dynamodb stream in the same request is from the same shard, which means they share the same key. It could mean I have to do bulk update on the same document in Elasticsearch. I wonder whether it is a good approach. Does bulk update run in parallel or in sequence?

I know I can consolidate them before updating in Elasticsearch. But I don't want to add any additional logic on the stream processing part.

Comment: what sort of updates are you doing and can you get your code to merge them before sending to Elasticsearch?

Comment: This is something I want to avoid. I'd like to keep the two data source in sync without any possibility of mutation during processing

Comment: does it matter which update is applied out of the multiple?

Comment: it needs to be in the same order. I think your question answers my question, it is not a good idea to use bluk api for that. if one in the middle fail, I'd like to retry from the failed one